# PHP Array Loop Condition

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Hi everyone nice to meet you

I have php script like this :

```
$string = array("aa", "bb-b1", "bb-b2", "bb-b3", "cc-c1", "cc-c2", "dd", "ee", "ff-f1", "ff-f2", "gg");

foreach($string as $text) {
    $exp = explode("-", $text);

    if(count($exp) == 1) {
        echo $text."\n";
    }
    else {
        list($first, $second) = $exp;
        
        echo $second."\n";
    }
}
```

Output : 
aa 
b1 
b2 
b3 
c1 
c2 
dd 
ee 
f1 
f2 
gg

But i want output like this : 
aa 
bb 
b1 
b2 
b3 
bb 
cc 
c1 
c2 
cc 
dd 
ee 
ff 
f1 
f2 
ff 
gg

Any trick or solution to make it...

Many thanks!

Comment: I think you might need to provide more details as to how/why you want your output structured in that way... as the code you've written is producing the result as expected (*the way it is coded*).

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the output

Comment: Before you ask the next time, please go read [ask]. You have given no explanation whatsoever, what the logic behind this is supposed to be. It is not our part here to try and figure that out based on your “I have, I want” example, but _your_ responsibility to properly explain that to begin with.

Comment: I am sorry.....

Comment: @KemalD. _why_ do you want/need to process this step-by-step? Your question doesn't mention that being a requirement, so dismissing others' answers based on that condition seems detrimental.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a for loop instead, you can keep track of the current letter and easily check the next item to determine if it's the same letter, a new letter, or the end of the array.

```
<?php

$string = array("aa", "bb-b7", "bb-b8", "bb-b9", "cc-c1", "cc-c2", "dd", "ee", "ff-f1", "ff-f2", "gg");
// other test cases:
//$string = array("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff", "gg");
//$string = array("aa-a1", "aa-a2", "aa-a3", "bb-b7", "bb-b8", "bb-b9");

$current = ''; // keep track of the current "letter"
$subItem = false; // keep track of if this is the first subitem we've seen or not
for($i=0; $i<count($string); $i++) {
    $exp = explode("-", $string[$i]);

    if(count($exp) == 1) {
        echo $string[$i]."\n";
    } else {
        list($first, $second) = $exp;
        
        // keep track of which letter we're on
        $current = $first;
        
        // output the "opening" letter (e.g. 'bb') if we're on the first in a list (e.g. 'bb-b1')
        if (!$subItem) {
            $subItem = true;
            echo $current."\n";
        }
        
        echo $second."\n";
        
        // if we're at the end of the array or are starting a new letter next
        if (!isset($string[$i+1]) || (explode("-", $string[$i+1])[0] != $current && $current != '')) {
            echo $current."\n";
            $subItem = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Working example at https://3v4l.org/YbVUG

Edit: updated the above script to handle the first subitems starting with any number, not just `1`.

Comment: almost perfect but output should be "BB" not "B", "CC" not "C", "FF" not "F",  I corrected the output

Comment: sorry your script not work if i change value after "-1" or "-2", like this "bb-b6", "bb-b7", "bb-b8", "cc-c6", "cc-c7", "dd", "ee", "ff-f6", "ff-f7"

Comment: Correct, based on your example it seemed like it would always start with `-b1` so that's how it's detecting the first subitem. This can be rewritten to cover that case, or use a modified version of @Lawrence's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66755690/1499877) for a more general case.

Comment: perfect WOUNDEDStevenJones, you save my day, thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Extra steps, but if you dont mind 2 loops, then create a normalised array first, then output the array in another loop:

```
<?php
$string = array("aa", "bb-b1", "bb-b2", "bb-b3", "cc-c1", "cc-c2", "dd", "ee", "ff-f1", "ff-f2", "gg");

$arr = [];
foreach ($string as $text) {
    $exp = explode("-", $text);
    
    if (count($exp) === 1) {
        $arr[$exp[0]] = [];
    } else {
        $arr[$exp[0]][] = $exp[1];
    }
}
```

`$arr` is now:

```
Array
(
    [aa] => Array
        (
        )

    [bb] => Array
        (
            [0] => b1
            [1] => b2
            [2] => b3
        )

    [cc] => Array
        (
            [0] => c1
            [1] => c2
        )

    [dd] => Array
        (
        )

    [ee] => Array
        (
        )

    [ff] => Array
        (
            [0] => f1
            [1] => f2
        )

    [gg] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Which you can easily output to the expected format

```
// output to expected format
foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
    echo empty($value) ? $key.PHP_EOL : $key.PHP_EOL.implode(PHP_EOL, $value).PHP_EOL.$key.PHP_EOL;
```

Result:

```
aa
bb
b1
b2
b3
bb
cc
c1
c2
cc
dd
ee
ff
f1
f2
ff
gg
```

Comment: sorry but I want to echo the process step by step

Comment: If you need it step-by-step, then instead of doing an implode, do something like `if (is_array($value)) { echo $key.PHP_EOL; foreach($value as $v) { echo $v.PHP_EOL; } echo $key.PHP_EOL; }`

Answer (score 1):

An exotic and short solution (array -> url query -> url parts -> echo):

```
parse_str(str_replace('-', '[]=', implode('&', $input)), $output);

foreach ($output as $key => $val)
{
    echo "$key\n";
    
    if ($val)
    {
        echo implode("\n", (array) $val) . "\n$key\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: very short but not what I expected, I want to echo the process step by step

Comment: you get what you ask :)

Comment: not yet, i want step by step

Answer (score 0):

here you go

```
<?php

$string = array("aa", "bb-b1", "bb-b2", "bb-b3", "cc-c1", "cc-c2", "dd", "ee", "ff-f1", "ff-f2", "gg");
foreach($string as $i){
    $x = explode('-', $i);
    $final = count($x) > 1 ? end($x) : $x[0];
    echo $final ."\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: does not match the output